Unable to connect to MQTT (AWS IoT Core) in a Flutter application
We have a Flutter application where the device subscribes to MQTT and can publish information. The application connects to AWS IoT Core using mqtt_client. The vast majority of devices running our app in production have no issues connecting to MQTT. However, we see a decent amount that are unable to establish a connection. Common error:
mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message (Missing Connection Acknowledgement?

Implementation:
      _client = MqttServerClient(
        awsIoTEndpoint,
        _clientIdentifier,
      );

      _client!.securityContext = context;
      _client!.logging(on: true);
      _client!.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
      _client!.port = 8883;
      _client!.secure = true;
      _client!.onConnected = onConnected;
      _client!.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
      _client!.pongCallback = pong;
      final mqttClientMessage =
          MqttConnectMessage().withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
      _client!.connectionMessage = mqttClientMessage;
      await _client!.connect();

We have verified that these devices have a valid internet connection. In some cases, we can see that other devices on the same network connect to MQTT with no issues.
Any troubleshooting help would be greatly appreciated!

This may be relevant.
